# Someone's smile VS Someone smile

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Which one of the following is correct?

1. Be the reason of **someone's smile**.
2. Be the reason of **someone smile**.

Million of thanks.

Comment: (2) does not make sense.

Comment: I would prefer "for" to "of". In the second you could also change "smile" to "to smile".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kate Bunting's comment that the second sentence does not make sense. The first sentence is having an apostrophe(') which indicates possession “person's smile = smile of a person”. Thus, in my opinion, it makes the first sentence more meaningful.